TeXstudio: I want to compile the whole file when hitting F5 in a subfile
I use \usepackage{subfiles} ... \subfile{subfilename.tex} in the main file.
How can I make latex compile the whole stuff and not only the subfile whenever I hit F5, regardless of which file is active in TeXstudio?
Background: When I have the subfile open in TeXstudio and hit F5, it only compiles the subfile. This causes many problems. For example, the references to the main file produce ??, and section numbers become incorrect even for the stuff in the subfile.

Did you try to insert the magic comment in the subfile to set the root document?

What is that? I only have \documentclass[./mainfilename.tex]{subfiles} etc. in the subfile.

@Convexity Try with % !TeX root = ./mainfilename.tex as first line your subfile

(why use subfiles if you want to compile the complete file?)

Thanks, that worked perfectly. \input did not allow me to hit F5 in the subfile, but - now with that magic comment, also \input works. Maybe I should use it, instead, from now on. Thank you very much for the solution to both problems! If you want to write an answer of that, I'll accept it.

I had this working without that magic comment before I installed TeXstudio 4.8.1.
At least I cannot come up with any other reason than the update, as I have changed almost nothing else. However, I'm fine without an explanation to that, as now things work again.
